# I want to retrieve data from SQ-lite in android studio in such a way that i want to print 4 random entries and "or" after two entries

Tags: java, database, sqlite, android-studio

I am developing an app for automatically generating question papers from a question bank stored in my database.

**This is my table in which i have questions as entries.**

[image]

**I want it to be in this format**

[image]

I also need to make sure that no questions are repeated in the question paper.

Comment: what do u want now. Query?

Comment: Yes.I have a query to retrieve 4 random values using random() but i want to retrieve it the format mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

That's not called selecting random records among programmers. Values selected randomly repeat more often than you think, and in fact counting the number and length of repeats is one way statisticians detect cheating.

What you're looking for is called a shuffle. Shuffling randomizes the order of a finite set of things, like cards or keys. (Randomizing the order of rows doesn't mean the same thing as selecting random rows.)

In your case, plan to store the set of keys already used for each user. Select a random set of rows that aren't already in that set. There are several ways to store each random set of rows (keys); make sure you can tell which one is the last or current set.

Comment: Right now i'm only concerned with the format in which i want to retrieve it .Like this :- q.1.a "question1"  01.b. "question2"   or  q.2.a "question3" q.2.b "question4"

Comment: can you help me with this ?

Comment: you can take random ques of mark 6 and 7. but the next time it may repeat the question. so store the first 4 random qno in set and try next random without the set.

Comment: First : select * from question where mark='6' order by RANDOM() limit 2;

Comment: in second iteration only you have to pass the qno set. first time the set will be empty

Comment: SELECT * FROM questions WHERE qid NOT IN (set) and mark = '6' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2;

Comment: how do i create a set? or is it automatically created?